# Android access to all child item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView which build up using a custom ListAdapter. I need to access to all the child item in list view in order to get all the text of TextView in in each item in ListView.

```
private void calcTotalSales ()
{
    View v;
    TextView tx;
    String abc="";
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todaySalesListView);
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        v = (View) myList.getChildAt(i);

        tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantityTB);
        Log.d ("Text", tx.getText().toString());

    }

}
```

Part in my listAdapter :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    final int _position = position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_today_sales_list_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTB);
        holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTB);
        holder.txt_itemQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantityTB);
        holder.txt_plusBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        holder.txt_minusBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minusBtn);
        holder.txt_plusBtn.setTag(holder);
        holder.txt_minusBtn.setTag(holder);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.txt_plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 //Set Text of TextView
            }


        });

        holder.txt_minusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //Set Text of TextView

            }
        });

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.txt_itemPrice.setText("RM "+itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemCost());

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is the problem i am facing :

1. I could not access to the first item in the listview
2. The access to the item is not consistent (meaning sometime it success and sometime it failed)

Anyone can helps ?

Comment: how you are setting the text for the TextView ?

Comment: instead of this access directly from where you have set data in listview

Comment: ListView recycle the views for the performance reasons. So it will allocate memory for the visible items in the list. i.e for example if you list has 100 items and you can see 10 items at a time, then listview will allocate memory for 10 views only. So what happens here is when you try to get the child first view when you scroll your list, you'll get NPE

Comment: Triode : I added in the code of ListAdapter
Dhawal , Pragani : Mind to share your solutions for this problem ?